# How to add Post request Body in Url in x-www-form-urlencoded request in Kotlin?

Tags: api, kotlin, generics, testing, web-api-testing

Hi im trying to do automation API testing using Kotlin now i need to add a post request for generating a token. The post method contains the content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and now i need to pass the body in x-www-form-urlencoded format. How can we achieve that.

""class Login: PostRequest()  {

```
override fun buildHttpRequestBuilder(): HttpRequest.Builder {
    val httpRequestBuilder = super.buildHttpRequestBuilder()
    httpRequestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    return httpRequestBuilder
}

override fun buildUrl(): String {
    return "URL"
}

override fun buildPostBody(): String {

    val body = JSONObject().apply {
        .field("grant_type", "client_credentials")"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrofit 1.9** You can add this annotation on your interface.

```kotlin
@Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
```

Retrofit 2.3+ version  add **@FormUrlEncoded** in your request api

demo code

```kotlin
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("mobileapi")
Observable<Result<YourData>> queryData(@Field("pageNo") Integer num);
```

Hope to bring you some help.